# For $\left|\frac{\alpha^n-\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}\right| \leq \frac{|\alpha|^n-|\beta|^n}{|\alpha|-|\beta|}$, what will happen when $|\alpha|=|\beta|$?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

For the complex inequality
$$
\left|\frac{\alpha^{n}-\beta^{n}}{\alpha-\beta}\right| \leq \frac{|\alpha|^{n}-|\beta|^{n}}{|\alpha|-|\beta|},\quad|\alpha|\neq|\beta|,\quad\alpha\in\mathbb{C},\quad\beta\in\mathbb{C}
$$
does it still hold for the case when $|\alpha|=|\beta|$, if not, how could we interpreted this case?

I try to rewrite $|\alpha|^n-|\beta|^n$ in form of
$$
|\alpha|^n-|\beta|^n=
(|\alpha|-|\beta|)(|\alpha|^{n-1}+|\beta||\alpha|^{n-2}+\cdots+|\alpha||\beta|^{n-2}+|\beta|^{n-1}),
$$
but is it true to obtain
$$
\frac{(|\alpha|-|\beta|)(|\alpha|^{n-1}+|\beta||\alpha|^{n-2}+\cdots+|\alpha||\beta|^{n-2}+|\beta|^{n-1})}{|\alpha|-|\beta|}=|\alpha|^{n-1}+|\beta||\alpha|^{n-2}+\cdots+|\alpha||\beta|^{n-2}+|\beta|^{n-1}.
$$

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It doesn't hold as you can't divide by zero.  period. However, I believe, it is true that if $\alpha\ne \beta$ then $|\frac{\alpha^n - \beta^n}{\alpha -\beta} \le |\alpha|^{n-1}+|\beta||\alpha|^{n-2}+\cdots+|\alpha||\beta|^{n-2}+|\beta|^{n-1}= n*|\alpha|^{n-1}=n*|\beta|^{n-1}$.  (... someone might wish to varify I'm not making a brain-farty erroneous statement...)

Comment: .... and even if $\alpha$ *does* equal $\beta$ it seems that $|\sum \alpha^k\beta^{n-k-1}| \le \sum |\alpha^k\beta^{n-k-1}|$.  But... you can't divide by zero.  ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the inequality can be rewritten as (and follows from the more obvious)

$$ |\alpha^{n-1}+\alpha^{n-2}\beta+\cdots+\alpha\beta^{n-2}+\beta^{n-1}|\le |\alpha|^{n-1}+|\alpha|^{n-2}|\beta|+\cdots+|\alpha||\beta|^{n-2}+|\beta|^{n-1} $$

This is simply an application of the triangle inequality to multiple summands, combined with the fact that absolute value is multiplicative. When $|\alpha|=|\beta|$ the right side becomes $n|\alpha|^{n-1}$ and the left side is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You would just take the limit of the right-hand side as $|\alpha|$  approaches $|\beta|$, which gives you $n|\beta|^{n-1} = n|\alpha|^{n-1}$.